# An easy and portable FreeType font library?

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts

I'd like to be able to draw text using FreeFonts.... I checked Nehe's tutorial as well as some other libraries he recommends like the FreeType project or OGLFT but they all seem to require installation of different components on the machine before being able to be used in the project. I need to keep my project completely independed, it comes with its own copies of all the GL files and libs, because the project needs to be compiled and run on a virgin machine by the professor...

Having said this, is there any library that can just be linked to the project and packed with it, that allows to read and raw a .tff font, also packed in the project? Worst comes to worst I could even use [Nehe's Bitmap Font](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/) technique but it seems like it relies on a Font inside the Windows system files.... I could definitely go for a Bitmap Font reader as long as I can read it from the project's directory....

Comment: You can probably hunt down the required components (most likely a few shared libraries) and deploy them together with your project.

Comment: The FreeType library can be statically linked, I think.

Comment: So, you are looking for a windows solution?

Answer (score 3):

FreeType *is* a library, and *can* build as a static library or shared/dynamic library.

As explained in the [INSTALL](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/docs/INSTALL) file, there are [project files](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/builds/) included with the distribution for doing just that. There is also documentation on [customizing the build](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/docs/CUSTOMIZE).

Comment: I can vouch this can be done :)

Comment: Thank you, but as a beginner programmer those links don't really make much sense to me, I can't really find the relation between what's mentioned there and the files in the package.... would you have a rough direction on how to compile that for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Alex: Did you even download the distribution and search for Visual Studio project files? Because it has some. Yes, not for VC2010, but VC2010 can work with VC2008 projects just fine.

Comment: There are VC2010 projects in the git repo, not sure if they're in a release: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git/tree/builds/win32/vc2010/